# $a_1=1$ and $a_n$ is randomly $a_{n-1}$ or $\frac12 a_{n-1}$. What is $\mathbb{P}[\sum a_n<\infty]$?

Tags: probability

Define a series of random variables by $a_1=1$, and $a_n$ is either $a_{n-1}$ or $\frac12 a_{n-1}$ with equal probabilities.

> What is the probability that the series $\sum a_i$ converges?

This is a tail event, thus by kolmogorov's 0-1 law this probability is **either 0 or 1**.

The expectation of the sum is $$S=\sum_{n\geq 1} \mathbb{E}[a_i]=1+ \sum_{n \geq2} \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[a_i|a_{i-1}]]=1+\sum_{n \geq2} \mathbb{E}[\frac34 a_{i-1}]=1+\frac34 S$$ and thus the expected value is $4$. Can we conclude from this that the series converges with probability 1?

Comment: This will sound very silly, but why does the above rule out $S = \infty$?

Comment: The correct proof continues with $E(a_n)=(3/4)^{n-1}$ for every $n\geqslant1$ hence $A=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}a_n$ is such that $E(A)=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}(3/4)^{n-1}$ is finite hence $A$ is almost surely finite.

Comment: Thanks, I see how $\mathbb{E}[a_n]=(\frac34)^{n-1}$ by induction. But why finite expectation shows finite sum a.e?

Comment: It's positive and has finite expectation, hence is finite a.s. ("If $X$ is a random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[\lvert X\rvert] < \infty$, then $X$ is finite almost surely.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was solved in the comments. Here's how I interpreted it.

First, the calculation of the expectation as written does not rule out $S=\infty$, and should be fixed by noting by induction that $\mathbb{E}[a_i]=(\frac34)^{i-1}$, since $\mathbb{E}[a_i] = \frac12 \mathbb{E}[a_{i-1}]+ \frac12 \mathbb{E}[\frac12a_{i-1}]=\frac34 \mathbb{E}[a_{i-1}]$. Then by a geometric series we get $\mathbb{E}[S]=4$.

Second, Since the sum $S$ is a non-negative random variable, we can invoke markov's inequality: We truncate $S$ to have value $5$ whenever it diverges to make all its values finite. This can only lower the expectation of $S$. (We truncate to avoid justifying the use of markov with a r.v. that does not get values in $\mathbb{R}$.)

So we have $4\geq\mathbb{E}[S]\geq 4.5\times\mathbb{P}[S\geq 4.5] $, and thus in particular the probabilty that sum diverges before our alteration is smaller than $1$, and by kolmogorov it is $0$.

A similar argument works whenever $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$ is finite:
We look at $|X|$, truncate it to  $n\mathbb{E}[|X|]$ when it diverges, and by Markov's inequality we get
 we have $\mathbb{P}[|X| \text{ diverges}] \leq \mathbb{P}[|X| \geq n\mathbb{E}[|X|]] \leq \frac1n$ for all $n$, hence it is $0$, and $X$ is finite a.e.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the finite series $\sum_n^M a_n$ for $M > 1$ which has a maximum of $M$

max$\sum_n^M a_n = M$ for  $M > 1$

$\mathbb{P}\big[\sum_n^M a_n=M\big]=\big(\frac{1}{2} \big)^{M-1}$

$\lim_{M\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\big[\sum_n^M a_n=M\big]=\lim_{M\to \infty}(1/2)^{M-1}=0$

$\Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}\big(\sum_n^M a_n<\infty\big) = 1-\lim_{M\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\big[\sum_n^M a_n=M\big]=1-0=1$

Comment: In the last row, why $\mathbb{P}\big(\sum_{n=1}^M a_n<\infty\big) = 1-\lim_{M\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\big[\sum_{n=1}^M a_n=M\big]$?

Comment: ℙ(S< M) = 1-ℙ(S=M) where S is the sum of a